# neural network trained with PyTorch outputs the mean value for every input

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, mnist

I am using [PyTorch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyTorch) in order to get my neural network to recognize digits from the [MNIST database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database).

```
import torch
import torchvision
```

I'd like to implement a very simple design similar to what is shown in [3Blue1Brown's video series about neural networks](https://www.3blue1brown.com/topics/neural-networks). The following design in particular achieved an error rate of [1.6%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database#Classifiers).

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(784, 800)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(800, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.layer1(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.layer2(x))
        return x
```

The data is gathered using torchvision and organised in mini batches containing 32 images each.

```
batch_size = 32
training_set = torchvision.datasets.MNIST("./", download=True, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())
training_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_set, batch_size=32)
```

I am using the mean squared error as a loss funtion and stochastic gradient descent with a learning rate of 0.001 as my optimization algorithm.

```
net = Net()
loss_function = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

Finally the network gets trained and saved using the following code:

```
for images, labels in training_loader:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    for i in range(batch_size):
        output = net(torch.flatten(images[i]))
        desired_output = torch.tensor([float(j == labels[i]) for j in range(10)])
        loss = loss_function(output, desired_output)
        loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
torch.save(net.state_dict(), "./trained_net.pth")
```

However, here are the outputs of some test images:

```
tensor([0.0978, 0.1225, 0.1018, 0.0961, 0.1022, 0.0885, 0.1007, 0.1077, 0.0994,
        0.1081], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
tensor([0.0978, 0.1180, 0.1001, 0.0929, 0.1006, 0.0893, 0.1010, 0.1051, 0.0978,
        0.1067], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
tensor([0.0981, 0.1227, 0.1018, 0.0970, 0.0979, 0.0908, 0.1001, 0.1092, 0.1011,
        0.1088], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
tensor([0.1061, 0.1149, 0.1037, 0.1001, 0.0957, 0.0919, 0.1044, 0.1022, 0.0997,
        0.1052], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
tensor([0.0996, 0.1137, 0.1005, 0.0947, 0.0977, 0.0916, 0.1048, 0.1109, 0.1013,
        0.1085], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
tensor([0.1008, 0.1154, 0.0986, 0.0996, 0.1031, 0.0952, 0.0995, 0.1063, 0.0982,
        0.1094], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
tensor([0.0972, 0.1235, 0.1013, 0.0984, 0.0974, 0.0907, 0.1032, 0.1075, 0.1001,
        0.1080], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
tensor([0.0929, 0.1258, 0.1016, 0.0978, 0.1006, 0.0889, 0.1001, 0.1068, 0.0986,
        0.1024], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
tensor([0.0982, 0.1207, 0.1040, 0.0990, 0.0999, 0.0910, 0.0980, 0.1051, 0.1039,
        0.1078], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
```

As you can see the network seems to approach a state where the answer for every input is:

```
[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

This neural network is not better than just guessing. Where did I go wrong in my design or code?

Comment: In your training code, add some code to tell if the loss is actually decreasing while training. [Example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#train-the-network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few points that would be useful for you:

- At first glance your model is not learning since your prediction are as good as a random guess. The first initiative would be to monitor your loss, here you only have a single epoch. At least you could evaluate your model on unseen data:

  ```
  validation_set = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./', 
      download=True, train=False, transform=T.ToTensor())

  validation_loader = DataLoader(validation_set, batch_size=32)
  ```
- You are using a MSE loss (the L2-norm) to train a classification task which is [not the right tool for this kind of task](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46413/can-the-mean-squared-error-be-used-for-classification). You could instead be using the negative log-likelihood. PyTorch offers [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) which includes a log-softmax and the negative log-likelihood loss in one module. This change can be implemented by adding in:

  ```
  loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
  ```

  and using the right target shapes when applying `loss_function` (*see below*). Since the loss function will apply a log-softmax, you **shouldn't have** an activation function on your model's output.
- You are using sigmoid as an activation function, intermediate non-linearities will work better as [ReLU](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08375.pdf) ([see related post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226923/why-do-we-use-relu-in-neural-networks-and-how-do-we-use-it)). A sigmoid is more suited for a binary classification task. Again, since we are using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`, we have to remove the activation after `layer2`.

  ```
  class Net(torch.nn.Module):
      def __init__(self):
          super(Net, self).__init__()
          self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
          self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(784, 800)
          self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(800, 10)

      def forward(self, x):
          x = self.flatten(x)
          x = torch.relu(self.layer1(x))
          x = self.layer2(x)
          return x
  ```
- A less crucial point is the fact that you could infer estimations on a whole batch instead of looping through each batch one element at a time. A typical training loop for one epoch would look like:

  ```
  for images, labels in training_loader:
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      output = net(images)
      loss = loss_function(output, labels)
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()
  ```

With these kinds of modifications, you can expect to have a validation of around 80% after a single epoch.

Comment: It is clearly mentioned "I'd like to implement a very simple design similar to what is shown in 3Blue1Brown's video series" and changing the activations would be going against that. I don't think that is the problem here.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia If you want to use sigmoid and MSE, you will have to train much longer to reach the same performance, that's up to you to decide.

Comment: If the problem tells you that it wants a fixed architecture then you can't change the architecture, even if ReLU has proven to be much better than sigmoid. It's just what the question demands - not your choice

Comment: Answers to closed-ended questions don't necessarily have to be closed-ended. I am providing an alternative approach that could prove valuable for users reading through this post. You are not the OP so I am not too concerned with the framing of my answer. Since you seem to be taking this one to heart, you should try to provide an answer yourself ;)

Comment: Indeed, your answer has proven to be very valuable to me. Your proposed modifications aren't too out of hand and easy to understand. @pu239 I should have been more specific when I said "simple design". Thank you for your concern.